# Updating a User model resets password? Rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller, I try updating a user instance's `rank` attribute (integer). For example from 1 to 2.

I do this by:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.rank = 2
@user.save(:validate => false)
```

For some reason the password for the user being saved gets erased, so that they can log in to my site without a password at all.  I've tried with and without the `:validate => false` parameter.

Any reason why? help?  Thanks a bunch

Model Code

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessible :login, :email, :fname, :lname, :password, :password_confirmation, :rank, :hours, :wars
    email_filter = /\A[\w+-.]+@[a-z\d-.]+.[a-z]+\z/i

```
validates :login, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 15, :minimum => 4 }, :uniqueness => true
validates :fname, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 2 }
validates :lname, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 2 }
validates :email, :presence => true, :format => { :with => email_filter}, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
validates :password,  :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :length => { :within =>4..40 }
validates :lane_id, :presence => true

before_save :encrypt_password
has_many :reports
has_many :accomplishments
belongs_to :lane 


def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate(login, submitted_password)
  user = find_by_login(login)
  return nil  if user.nil?
  return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end

def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
  user = find_by_id(id)
  (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
end

def current_report
  report = (Report.order("created_at DESC")).find_by_user_id(@user.id)
end

private

def encrypt_password
  self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
end

def encrypt(string)
  secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
end

def make_salt
  secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
end

def secure_hash(string)
  Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
end
```

end

Comment: Do you have any before or after filter?

Comment: no, just standard rails forms that are default

Comment: hmm, I have a before_save :encrypt_password.  Would that do it?  I am calling :validate => false though...

Comment: post the code for your user model

Comment: alright, I'm guessing that because I'm saving the user, and theres a before_save filter to encrypt a "non-existent" password, it makes it blank?

Comment: Yes. If there is no password, it would still encrypt the password.

Comment: So I assume that I can put a little check in the function that will cancel the entire thing if a password isnt sent in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `before_filter` that encrypts the password everytime you save your model. Instead of a `before_filter` use something like this:

```
def password=(new_password)
  self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(new_password)
end
```

Comment: so don't use the before_save :encrypt_password" then?

Comment: Exactly. `before_save` is called each time you save your model, and this code is only called when you update your password.

Comment: If I get rid of the before_save call, then the whole encryption process never takes place since "encrpyt_password" is only called once at the top.. so I'm still a little confused..

Comment: Each time you set your password, `password=` gets called, and if you take a look at my code, then you'll see that you get your encrypted password.

Comment: So I got rid of the 
    'before_save :encrypt_password' 
line altogether, and renamed the 'encrpyt_password' function to 'password=(new_password)'
but when I try updating, nothing changes.  Am I doing the change right?

Comment: You have to change the line: `self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)` to `self.encrypted_password = encrypt(new_password)` too.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, I did that change as well, same thing

Comment: It seems that the way it is now, no action is even taking place on the password.  I can type literally anything in, or nothing at all, and no actions are being called now

Comment: I ended up just checking to see if a password was passed in at all.  If nothing is passed in, then the whole encryption stuff will not initialize.

    def encrypt_password
    if (password)
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end
    end

Comment: You probably don't want the new_record? part, otherwise you can't update it.

Answer (score 3):

You only want to encrypt the password if one is present, so add a condition to your callback

```
before_save :encrypt_password, :unless => "password.blank?"
```

Also, you do not want to validate the password every time you update the user record.  You can remove the `:presence => true` validation, and add a condition to run the other validations only when the password is present.

```
validates :password,  :confirmation => true, :length => { :within =>4..40 }, :unless => "password.blank?"
```

Comment: that doesn't really work for some reason with Rails 3.2.2. Password is not an empty string anymore. Everytime I change user object with this code, encrypted password string is different, while it should be the same if the password is blank.

Comment: Is `password` a virtual attribute on your model (which is a typical implementation)?  If so the you must be setting the password in your code somewhere.  If not, then there is a more lengthy discussion which needs to take place than befits comments.

Comment: No, it's the real database field. But I still don't get it. When Rails executes UPDATE on DB, it only updates fields which are in the query, and password is not. I'm switching from PHP where I mostly performed direct queries from PHP clases, so I'm still not really used to ORM

Comment: First of all, it sounds like you are saving your users' unencrypted passwords in the `password` field and their encrypted passwords in the `encrypted_password` field.  Saving the unencrypted password defeats the purpose of encrypting, and in your case it also triggers the encryption process on every save because the password is not blank.  Take a look at this recipe for creating authentication in Rails http://asciicasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch.

Comment: Also, there are several good plugins out there which will add authentication to your app for you.  Check out Devise, which seems to be the most popular right now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is severely late, but I actually just stumbled across this article on [therailsways.com](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/8/3/users-and-passwords/) that was written back in 2009, but still worked for me in case anyone else who comes here through Google might have this same problem.

```
before_save :encrypt_password, :if => :password_changed?
```

I was having the same problem where my password would be re-encrypted on update, but I only wanted to encrypt it on user creation.

I was looking for alternatives to `before_save`, but none of them really did the trick. This however, certainly did, and all I had to do was add that if condition. It worked perfectly.